# Return second promise TypeScript Jquery promise

Tags: jquery, typescript, promise

In the function below I am trying to return the promise object of 2nd async call, However typescript complains that the function must return a value. I am not sure how can I accomplish this ? How do I return the 2nd promise ?

```
 private getSalesUrl<TServiceInput>(serviceCall: (args: TServiceInput) => JQueryPromise<IServiceResponseT>, args): JQueryPromise<any> {
        serviceCall(args).done(result => {  //1st async call
            if (result.serviceOutput) {
                if (result.serviceOutput.key === "URL") {
                    return tipsInterop.executeSalesRequest(result.serviceOutput.value);  //2nd async call
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The `return` is in the `done` callback of `serviceCall()`. You need to `return serviceCall(...)` in order to for the inner return to be returned by serviceCall...

Comment: If I return the serviceCall, then getSalesUrl.done() will be executed in the context of 1st async call. I want getSaleUrl.done() to be executed in the context of 2nd async call.

Comment: A) never use `done` or `fail`, always use `then`. B) you're not actually returning anything from `getSalesUrl` yet, you only `return` from the done callback

Comment: @Bergi I agree I am not returning anything right now, but how do I return the second promise ? can you please help ?

Comment: @NirbhayJha You cannot. But [using `then` will create a new promise that resolves with the inner result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

- Based on what the OP requested and the SO comments, I'm assuming the OP needs the second request's promise to be returned
- This should not be limited to TypeScript or JavaScript since its the basic functionality of the ajax call
- This example uses simple javascript and Jquery ajax requests

```js
var requests = {
  firstRequest: function() {
    return $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
  },
  secondRequest: function() {
    return $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2');
  }
};

var processResults = {
  callService: function() {
    return requests.firstRequest().then((data, textStatus, promise) => {
      return requests.secondRequest().then((data2, textStatus2, promise2) => {
        return "This is the content of second call: id=>" + data2.id;
      });
    });
  }
};

processResults.callService().then((data, textStatus, promise) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note:

- I'm returning the second call's data wrapped into a promise (by default if you return data from then call it gets wrapped into a new promise as commented by @Bergi)
- This is one way to pass intercept and pass the data
- The other way to pass the second call's data is to return promise2 i.e. use `return promise2` instead of `return "This is the content of second call: id=>"+ data2.id;`

Below is how it appears if the you swap it with `return promise2;`

```js
var requests = {
  firstRequest: function() {
    return $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
  },
  secondRequest: function() {
    return $.ajax('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2');
  }
};

var processResults = {
  callService: function() {
    return requests.firstRequest().then((data, textStatus, promise) => {
      return requests.secondRequest().then((data2, textStatus2, promise2) => {
        return promise2;
      });
    });
  }
};

processResults.callService().then((data, textStatus, promise) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```